# Installation setup problem (Access a checkbox in custom dialog box)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

> I’m trying to create a  installation setup for my VB.net application. I
>   need to insert a custom action while setup is running. So I add a
>   Checkbox Dialog box to my setup. And I add a dll to the setup
>   installation to capture Before Install and After Install events. Those
>   are works fine. But I cannot access my check box value in those
>   events. If u guys can give me a hint to continue my work really
>   appreciates.
>
> Following is the Before Install event I have created. I have set some
>   messages to verify my event works correctly. While I run the setup
>   those messages are prompt properly.

```
Private Sub Installer_BeforeInstall(ByVal sender As Object, _
                               ByVal e As System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs) Handles MyBase.BeforeInstall
    Dim koFaxPath As String = Nothing
    MsgBox("Installer_BeforeInstall: Starts1")

    Dim contextParameters As StringDictionary
    Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim actionDataName As String = String.Empty
    Dim arrayActionData() As String

    contextParameters = Me.Context.Parameters
    For Each actionDataName In Me.Context.Parameters.Keys
        arrayActionData = Me.Context.Parameters(actionDataName).ToString.Split("-")
        MsgBox(actionDataName.ToString)
        MsgBox(arrayActionData(0).ToString)
        MsgBox(Me.Context.Parameters.Item(actionDataName.ToString))
    Next


    Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        'needs to impliment
    End Try

    MsgBox("Installer_BeforeInstall: Ends")
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer for that. It may useful for u as well.
Once you have add your dll to the setup project, Go to dll properties.
There is a property called CustomActionData. Fill it as follows

```
/CheckBoxSequenceGenerator="[CheckBoxName]"
```

Now you can access this in following code

```
Context.Parameters("CheckBoxSequenceGenerator")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your check-box property are not assigned to coding.